# Send int array in POST RequestParams AsyncHttpClient Android App

Tags: java, android, ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I am currently developing an android app that send some requests to an API which is done in Ruby On Rails.

I have to make a request and one of the params is an `ArrayList<Integer>`. I pass it like this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> userIds = ...;
//...
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
params.put("conversation[user_ids]", userIds);
```

When I send the request, the API gets this array as a hash. If my `userIds` is:

```
[1,2]
```

in the API I get

```
"user_ids"=>{"0"=>"1", "1"=>"2"}
```

and what I would really like to get is

```
"user_ids"=>{[1,2]}
```

or something like that.

How can I sent an `ArrayList<Integer>` to the API so it would get recognized by it as an array in ruby and not as a hash? For this, I cannot modify the ruby code in the server, only the client side in the android app.

Comment: What about: `userIds.toArray()` ?

Comment: What do you mean "as a hash"?  Is it a `HashMap` or some other class?

Comment: it's the same, the API receives a hash. And if I send an int[] the API receives the reference and not the array itself.

Comment: a ruby on rails Hash, because the API Im sending the request to its made in Ruby on Rails. I just don't know to send an integer array so rails recognise it as an integer array an not as a hash.

Comment: `and userIds is an ArrayList`. Try to offer an int array instead.

Comment: if I send an int[] the API receives the reference and not the array itself.

Comment: How does that look? References cannot be transferred to another computer.

Comment: Like this: "user_ids"=>"[I@4210c9d0"}

Comment: Is this an Android method? Or you're using some lib ?

Comment: I am making a request using AsynHttpClient in my android app, it is a POST request to I used RequestParams to put params and send them to the server.

Comment: Try `params.put("user_ids", userIds);`. what does that?

Comment: That creates a pair key value which key is "user_ids" and value is then arrayList userIds, the I call AsyncHttpClient's POST function and add the variable params to it and send them.

Comment: Yes. But how does it look then?

Comment: If I print params it looks like this: 

conversation[user_ids][0]=1&conversation[user_ids][1]=2

Comment: How about passing the array in the `ArrayList` as a `String`?: `params.put("conversation[user_ids]", Arrays.deepToString(userIds.toArray()));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to fix it from the back-end point (ROR) by transforming the received param, it could be easily done with some ruby code like:

```
{"0"=>"1", "1"=>"2"}.values.map(&:to_i)
# > [1,2]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Android, but to pass an array of integers to rails you would use

```
conversation[user_ids][]=1&converstaion[user_ids][]=2&conversation[user_ids][]=3
```

So I'm guessing you could iterate over the `ArrayList` and then

```
params.put("conversation[user_ids][]", integer_member);
```

for every member of the array.